# Linear sum of (complete) lattices is a (complete) lattice.

Tags: solution-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders

Please, I need help to prove the following result. I tried to write a proof, but I think that it's full of *bugs*

**Theorem**

Let $P,Q$ be two (complete) lattices. Then $P\oplus Q$ is a (complete) lattice.

*My idea so far*

Let $a,b\in P\oplus Q$, I would like to show that $a\vee b, a\wedge b\in P\oplus Q$.

Definition (**Linear sum**): Let $P,Q$ be two (disjoint) ordered sets. $P\oplus Q$ is $P\cup Q$ (disjoint union) with the following order relation:

$$x\le y\mbox{ in } P\oplus Q \iff\begin{matrix} x\le y \mbox{ in }P, \mbox{ if }x,y\in P \mbox{ or }\\ x\le y \mbox{ in }Q, \mbox{ if }x,y\in Q\mbox{ or}\\ x\in P \mbox{ and } y\in Q.\end{matrix}$$

Let $a,b\in P\oplus Q$.

*Case 1.* If $a,b\in P$, then $a\vee b,a\wedge b\in P$, so these elements belong to $P\oplus Q.$

*Case 2.* If $a,b\in Q$, then $a\vee b,a\wedge b\in Q$, so these elements belong to $P\oplus Q.$

*Case 3.* If $a\in P$ and $b\in Q$, then $a\le b$ in $P\oplus Q.$ Let us consider the set

$$U=\{a,b\}^u=\{x\in P\oplus Q\ |\ a\le x\mbox{ and }b\le x\}$$

It is not empty because $b$ belongs to it. Moreover $b$ is the least element of U, so $a\vee b=b$. Since $b\in Q$, then $a\vee b\in P\oplus Q$.

Let us consider the set

$$L=\{a,b\}^l=\{x\in P\oplus Q\ | \ x\le a,x\le b\}$$

It is not empty because $a\in L$. Moreover $a$ is the biggest element of L, so $a\wedge b=a\in P\implies a\wedge b\in P\oplus Q.$

I think I can conclude that $P\oplus Q$ is a lattice. Is this a correct proof? If not, could you help me to fix it? Thanks.

Regarding completeness, I still have to think about it. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case 3, you don't have to go through all that.
If $a\in P$ and $b \in Q$, then, as you deduced, $a \leq b$, and it immediately follows that $a \wedge b = a$ and $a \vee b = b$.

Regarding completeness, if $P$ and $Q$ are complete, take $A \subseteq P \cup Q$, and you need to show that $\bigvee A \in P \oplus Q$ (I suppose you are aware that if this is true for any such $A$, then $P \oplus Q$ is also closed under arbitrary meets).
Now there are two cases, if $A \subseteq P$, then $\bigvee A \in P$ (it's the same in $P \oplus Q$ as in $P$);
otherwise, taking $A' = A \cap Q$, we have $\bigvee A = \bigvee A'$ (calculated in $Q$).

Comment: You're right, I was too verbose in case 3. Regarding completeness, I thought I'd consider the sets $A_P:=A\cap P$ and $A_Q:=A\cap Q$, where A Is a subset of $P\oplus Q$. Since $P,Q$ are complete, there exist $\bigvee A_P,\bigwedge A_P, \bigvee A_Q, \bigwedge A_Q\in P\oplus Q$. Additionally, $ \bigvee A=\bigvee A_P\vee \bigvee A_Q$ belongs to $P\oplus Q$, because it's a lattice. Same for Met. Is this reasoning ok?

Comment: @Ixion Yes, that is OK too. But again, you're being more verbose than I did in my approach. I don't thin it is too much, but if, for example $A\cap Q\neq\varnothing$, then the elements of $A$ which may lie in $P$ play no role in computing the join of $A$; likewise, if $A\cap P\neq\varnothing$, the elements of $A$ that may lie in $Q$ play no role in computing the meet of $A$. But it doesn't hurt to include them; they're just redundant.

Comment: @Ixion Another redundancy in your reasoning is that it's enough to show that there are joins of all subsets. Indeed, if in a poset all subsets have join, then given a subset $A$, if $L$ is the set of lower bounds of $A$, then $L$ as a join, by hypothesis, and $\bigwedge A=\bigvee L$. Notice that we demand all subsets, including the empty set (the join of the empty set, if it exists is the minimum of the poset; the meet of the empty set is the maximum). Equivalently (it if turns out to be simpler, in some example) show that every subset has meet, and you're done.

Comment: thanks amrsa. your comments are so enlightening. i am studying the lattices by myself. This is why my arguments are redundant. I hope to improve soon thanks also to your suggestions. :)